# Mongoid - how to get second record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I can do

`1.9.3p125 :122 > User.first

 => #<StandardUser _id: 4f849..`

and

`1.9.3p125 :124 > User.last`

and

`1.9.3p125 :125 > User.count

 => 5`

but I can't find any way to get at the other records (2 thru 4).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`User.skip(1).first` returns you second document.

Comment: Is there a way to get a second-from-last item similarly?